# run WEKA on Linux

Tags: java, linux, class, weka

I have downloaded and unzipped the following WEKA version weka-3-4-19. This is on a linux operating system. I wish to use WEKA through the command line, however on executing

```
java weka.classifiers.tress.j48.J48
```

I get the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weka/classifiers/tress/j48/J48
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weka.classifiers.tress.j48.J48
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: weka.classifiers.tress.j48.J48.  Program will exit.
```

Can someone help me resolve this? Thank you.

---

Edit1:

On trying the java -jar weka.jar command

```
java.awt.HeadlessException:
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:159)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:432)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:403)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:202)
    at weka.gui.GUIChooser.<init>(GUIChooser.java:98)
    at weka.gui.GUIChooser.main(GUIChooser.java:285)

No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
```

---

Edit 2:

On trying java.weka.classifiers.trees.J48

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weka/classifiers/tress/J48
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weka.classifiers.tress.J48
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: weka.classifiers.tress.J48.  Program will exit.
```

---

Edit 3:

```
{cslinux2:~/weka-3-4-19} echo $CLASSPATH
/people/cs/j/jld082000/weka-3-4-19/weka.jar:
{cslinux2:~/weka-3-4-19} java weka.classifiers.trees.J48

Weka exception: No training file and no object input file given.

General options:

-t <name of training file>
    Sets training file.
-T <name of test file>
    Sets test file. If missing, a cross-validation will be performed on the training data.
```

Comment: edit3: what exactly do you expect?  you didn't give it any data....  You can pass it data through the command line like it is telling you, or pull up the GUI using the way I mentioned

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That simply means `weka.classifiers.tress.j48.J48` class is not in [classpath](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html). You can write `java` command with `-classpath` switch or set CLASSPATH (permanent) variable. Another way is to use `-jar` switch as pointed by @jberg.

**EDIT:**

As I checked (I downloaded Weka 3-4-19 from [that site](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/index_downloading.html)) there is definitely no `weka.classifiers.tress.j48.J48` class in `weka.jar` package. Probably you are looking for:

```
java weka.classifiers.trees.J48
```

For example:

```
$ export CLASSPATH=/home/grzegorz/weka-3-4-19/weka.jar:.
$ echo $CLASSPATH 
/home/grzegorz/weka-3-4-19/weka.jar:.
$ java weka.classifiers.trees.J48

Weka exception: No training file and no object input file given.

General options:

-t <name of training file>
    Sets training file.
...
```

Comment: This is something I tried. After which I called the function in my question. Am I missing something? Thank you.     export CLASSPATH=/people/cs/j/jld082000/weka-3-4-19/weka.jar:$CLASSPATH

Comment: @rookie: You exported CLASSPATH, but there is no `weka.classifiers.tress.j48.J48` class in `weka.jar` library. See my updated answer.

Comment: Please see Edit2 to my question. It still errored out. I find it hard to understand what might be the matter. Also, how did you find out what's available in the weka.jar library? Thank you.

Comment: @rookie: Try using example commands in my answer. `weka.jar` is just ZIP archive, so you can look into it (e.g. weka/classifiers/tress directory means weka.classifiers.tress package).

Comment: Awesome! It worked. I thank you. I wish to say, however, the only additional thing I did was echo the classpath variable. How important is that? Yes, I am new to using the Linux commands.

Comment: @rookie: Uhm, AFAIK there is no "magic" in `echo` command :) It just displays CLASSPATH's value on standard output stream, nothing less, nothing more.

Answer (score 8):

This "weka.classifiers.trees.j48.J48" is a typo in the Weka documentation. It's should be this: "weka.classifiers.trees.J48"

And instead of setting the $CLASSPATH the alternative is just to put:

```
java -cp /pathto/weka.jar weka.classifiers.trees.J48
```

Also, you might want to give it more memory to play with, to speed things up:

```
java -Xmx1G -cp /pathto/weka.jar weka.classifiers.trees.J48
```

For running a classifier (like you are attempting to do) you need to at least give it some data, which must already be converted to ARFF format.

To run a test on some data enter:

```
java -Xmx1G -cp /path/to/weka.jar weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -t /path/to/whatever.arff
```

-t is for training file.

See here:
[Weka Primer](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Primer)

Comment: More useful than the accepted answer, especially for beginners looking to use Weka from the command

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used WEKA on linux, but I think it is just packaged as a jar file, so you want to:

`java -jar weka.jar`

You can also use the weka source jars to use the classifiers in your own code by including it in your build path like you would other jars.

Comment: I am not sure what the X11 DISPLAY variable is.

Answer (score 0):

I run the Linux Developer version in macOS. You can copy the `.bash_profile` below and modify to your needs.

As I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813795/could-not-find-or-load-main-class-when-calling-weka), you can just put the following to your `~/.bash_profile`

```
export R_HOME="/Applications/R.app/Contents/MacOS/R"    #for WEKA MLR R plugin 
export CLASSPATH="/Applications/weka-3-9-1/weka.jar"    #for WEKA commandline
export WEKAINSTALL="/Applications/weka-3-9-1"

export WEKA_HOME="/Applications/weka-3-9-1"
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH;$WEKA_HOME/weka.jar
export HEAP_OPTION=-Xms4096m -Xmx8192m
export JAVA_COMMAND java $HEAP_OPTION
```

after this and refreshing the terminal, you should be able to run the following command

```
java weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -t $WEKAINSTALL/data/iris.arff
```